# How can I run WhatsApp on Ubuntu using ARC Welder?

Tags: google-chrome, android, whatsapp

**Background:**

I am trying to run WhatsApp on Ubuntu 16.04 using the [ARC Welder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) Chrome app.

The following animation displays the procedure as well as the error.

Did someone succeed running WhatsApp using this method?

**Animation:**

[image]